# How to set-up multi node WildFly cluster in same machine?

Tags: cluster-computing, wildfly, wildfly-8

How can i set-up

> multiple nodes of WildFly in a single machine in Clustered mode ?

***Should i create multiple Standalone nodes or multiple Domain nodes if I want to create all these multiple nodes in my 1 machine ?***

*Reason i want to have all nodes in 1 machine is because currently I am learning & validating few of it's capabilities.*

***Note***: I referred to this http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=1952 but, i keep getting the following error

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.network.public: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.network.public: JBAS015810: failed to resolve interface public
    at org.jboss.as.server.services.net.NetworkInterfaceService.start(NetworkInterfaceService.java:96) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
```

Updated understanding on Standalone vs Domain:
The HA or Failover feature provided by the multiple nodes in a cluster is the same between Standalone or Domain mode. The difference is that, in Domain mode, it allows the admins to manage/deploy all the nodes via a single (domain controler) node's Admin Console. This URL has a good explanation on it

Ref: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Admin+Guide#AdminGuide-

***Update***: As of now for learning purpose, i have configured to run multiple nodes in my machine using Domain mode blog.arungupta.me/wildfly-8-clustering-and-session-failover

Comment: Try set `port-offset` for each instance http://planet.jboss.org/post/multiple_instances_of_wildfly_on_different_ports_on_same_machine_tech_tip_8

Answer (score 6):

Try to execute two or more instances on the same machine using a HA profile, choose the standalone-ha.xml. For example, on the same machine:

```
%WILDFLY_HOME_1%/standalone.bat -c standalone-ha.xml -Djboss.node.name=srv1;
```

and

```
%WILDFLY_HOME_2%/standalone.bat -c standalone-ha.xml -Djboss.node.name=srv2 -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100
```

and you'll have a cluster of two nodes on the same machine, the first one bound to port `8080` and the second one bound to port `8180`. There is no need configuring a domain to have a cluster.

Comment: but how do these standalone nodes know that they are the HA pair ? is there any configuration where i should mention the node names of these 2 HA nodes ?  i understand that we can use a load balancer in-front of these 2 nodes to split user requests between these 2 nodes but, how is the "Session Clustering" kind of features gets executed between these 2 HA Nodes ?

Comment: Wildfly uses JGroups plus Infinispan to turn instances to cluster's node and share session infos (HTTP Session and Stateful EJB). Communication between nodes use by default a multicast address, take a look at `<socket-binding-group>` at the bottom of the `standalone-ha.xml`, you should find some `<socket-binding name="jgroups...>` entries. Hope this helps.

Comment: does this mean that, once i create and run the 2 nodes in my machine, they automatically work like belonging to a single HA Cluser and I don't have to do any configuration for it ?   Note: Assuming that I haven't touched the configuration/standalone-ha.xml file in my both "standalone-node1" and "standalone-node2" folders.

Comment: You should be able to see it in the log. The first node should report that the second one has joined the cluster. Did you try it?